# What is wrong with my proof that $A_6$ has no subgroup of order 72

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to show that $A_6$ has no subgroup of order 72. This is what I came up with:

Suppose that $A_6$ did have a subgroup $H$ of order 72. We know that $A_6$ has order $360$, so $[A_6,H]=5$. Let $A_6$ act on the five right cosets of $H$ by left translation, i.e. $g(Ha)=H(ga)$. This is clearly a group action. This action has the effect of permuting the the cosets of $H$. We may therefore define a homomorphism from $\phi:A_6\to S_5$ by $\phi(g)$ maps to the permutation realized by the action of $g$ on the right cosets of $H$. The kernel of this homomorphism is a normal subgroup of $A_6$. Observe that 
\begin{align*}
\ker\phi&=\{g\in A_6:g(Ha)=Ha\;\;\;\forall a\in A_6\}\\
&=\{g\in A_6:H(ga)=Ha\;\;\;\forall a\in A_6\}\\
&=\{g\in A_6:(ga)a^{-1}\in H\;\;\;\forall a\in A_6\}\\
&=\{g\in A_6:g\in H\}\\
&=H.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $H$ is a normal subgroup of $A_6$ of order 72, which is not possible because $A_6$ is simple. Therefore, we conclude that no such subset $H$ exists.

I cannot find any problems with this proof except that I never really used the order of $H$ and the order of $A_6$. It seems like I could use the same argument to show that any simple group has no proper, nontrivial subgroups. This is obviously false, so what is wrong?

Comment: You used the orders when you observed $H$ had index 5 in $A_6$. Indeed, simple groups can't have subgroups of small indices, for exactly this reason.

Comment: But if this proof technique were valid, I could replace 72 with any factor of 360, and it would still work.

Comment: Ok, I see your confusion. The kernel is not $H$, but rather the intersection of all conjugates of $H$.

Comment: Nevermind, I see you are trying to mix left and right action.

Comment: Yep. I have revised my proof now, and I am happy with it because it uses the fact that you cannot have an injective homomorphism from $A_6$ into $S_5$, thereby utilizing the cardinalities of $A_6$ and $H$.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a sound idea, but I don't see why $g(Ha)=Ha$ implies
$H(ga)=Ha$. But you don't need this calculation. The image of $\phi$
is transitive, so has order between $5$ and $120$. Therefore the
kernel has order between $6$ and $144$, so is proper, violating the
simplicity of $A_6$.